# How can rotation be produced if moment of force of reaction is zero?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, torque

My book mentions that:
*The moment of the force of reaction about the pivot is zero because its distance from the axis of rotation is zero ,  The pair of forces formed by the external force and the force of reaction is called a couple . Thus , no equal and opposite parallel forces , not acting along the same line , form a couple . A couple is always needed to produce a rotation .* **The book mentions that the couple is necessary for rotation to happen but if the moment of force of reaction is zero then how rotation can be produced?**

Comment: Which book is this?

Comment: Concise Physics-ICSE Part II (Class X)